# git add for each laravel's "artisan generate" command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there any way to add to git every auto-generated (by laravel artisan) file with one simple command? I forgot to add new files to git everytime I run `php artisan make:migration` or similar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following, but mind you, the solution below will add **any untracked files**, so it will be helpful when the only untracked files are the ones that are being generated by the `artisan` command.

Create a `git` alias that adds any untracked files (the alias is to make it easier to write the command). Run this to edit the git config:

```
git config --global --edit
```

Then add the following alias:

```
[alias]
adduntracked=!git add $(git ls-files -o --exclude-standard)
```

You can now append `&& git adduntracked` after the `artisan` command to add the new files, all in one line:

```
php artisan make:migration the_migration_name && git adduntracked
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, +1. Is there any solution to just add the created file?